# what is the difference between System.out.write and System.out.print in java

Tags: java

I want to know where is the difference between `System.out.write` and `System.out.print` in my Java class.

Comment: It is actually no big difference, you inherit the write from the underlying output stream. You can use both but print/printf is typically more convinient (especially as it supresses exceptions).

Comment: For me I used System.out.write() but it didnt work,I change it to println and it works.I still didnt understand why.

Answer (score 7):

The two methods of `PrintStream` have different meanings:

- `print(int)` writes a decimal representation of the entire `int`, while
- `write(int)` writes the least significant byte of the specified `int` to the output.

This leads to different results: if you call `print(48)`, the output is going to be `48`, but if you call `write(48)`, the output would be system-dependent, but on most systems it would be `0`.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/iHqT34)

Comment: Is it really system-dependent? I thought Java always used UTF-16.

Comment: @immibis When you work with characters, it does. But the `write` call is on the byte level, not on the character level, so the system is free to interpret that byte in a system-specific way.

Comment: Oh right. I forgot it's not a PrintWriter.