# writing console output in java

Tags: java, console, output

```
class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String args[]) {
int b;
b = 'A';
System.out.write(b);
System.out.write('\n');
System.out.write(97);
System.out.write('\n');
System.out.write(1889); 
System.out.write('\n');
}
}
```

output of this program is

```
A
a
a
```

How does the following line  produce **a** as the output.

```
System.out.write(1889);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `1889 % 256 = 97`. There are 256 ASCII characters, so the `mod operator` is used to get a valid character.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28522116) `System.out.write(int)` writes the least significant byte to the output in a system-dependent way. In your case, the system decided to write it as a character.

```
1889 == 0000 0111 0110 0001
  97 == 0000 0000 0110 0001
```

The right-most octet is the same for both numbers. As @Cricket mentions, this is essentially the same as taking the modulus of the number you pass in and 256.